# Why am I getting 'invalid command' from Poloniex API with Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, poloniex

I'm trying to use my Poloniex API secret and key to check balances on my account.  However, I keep getting "`invalid command`" returned as a response.

Below is my code in Python3:

```
        command = 'returnBalances'
        req['command'] = command
        req['nonce'] = int(time.time()*1000)
        post_data = urllib.parse.urlencode(req).encode()

        sign = hmac.new(str.encode(self.Secret), post_data, hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()
        headers = {
            'Sign': sign,
            'Key': self.APIKey
        }

        print(post_data)
        req = urllib.request.Request(url='https://poloniex.com/tradingApi', headers=headers)
        res = urllib.request.urlopen(req, timeout=20)

        jsonRet = json.loads(res.read().decode('utf-8'))
        return self.post_process(jsonRet)
```

`print(post_data)` returns what i would expect to see:

```
b'nonce=1491334646563&command=returnBalances'
```

Comment: Looks like you are not sending `post_data` with the request (I assume you must send it in the POST body).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you must send the `post_data` with the request. I like to use the `requests` library instead of `urllib` directly, but it should be something like this with plain `urllib`:

```
req = urllib.request.Request('https://poloniex.com/tradingApi', post_data, headers)
```

Comment: Thanks! i thought post_data was included with the header in the "sign=" line.  I'm very new with this urllib stuff and im just trying to hack a preexisting API wrapper to work with python 3.

Answer (score 8):

**Send Content-Type header**

This [excellent article](https://kaijento.github.io/2017/05/05/poloniex-api-invalid-command/) pointed me to the right direction. It appears python 3's request library skips sending Content-Type header, which causes Polo to reject the request.

```
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

headers:

```
headers = {
    'Sign': hmac.new(SECRET.encode(), post_data, hashlib.sha512).hexdigest(),
    'Key': API_KEY,
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}
```